# Move folders in subfolders

Tags: batch-file, cmd, robocopy

I don't know if the title is clear enough.
This is what I am trying to do :

**Actual folder structure :**

```
Root_Folder
 |
 +-- Folder1
 |    
 +-- Folder2
 |  |  
 |  +-- file 2.1
 |    
 +-- Folder3
 |  |  
 |  +-- file 3.1
 |  +-- file 3.2
 |    
 +-- Folder 4
 |  |  
 +  |-- Subfolder 4.1
```

**The folder structure I would like :**

```
Root_Folder
 |
 +-- Folder1
 |  |
 |  +-- Documents
 |
 +-- Folder2
 |  |  
 |  +-- Documents
 |  |  |
 |  |  +-- file 2.1
 |    
 +-- Folder3
 |  |  
 |  +-- Documents
 |  |  |
 |  |  +-- file 3.1
 |  |  +-- file 3.2
 |    
 +-- Folder 4
 |  |  
 |  +-- Documents
 |  |  |
 |  |  +-- Subfolder 4.1
```

**The script I came up with :**

```
SET ROOT_FOLDER=C:\Folder\Root
SET WORK_FOLDER=C:\Temp
SET FILE_LIST=%WORK_FOLDER%\list.txt
DIR %ROOT_FOLDER% >%FILE_LIST% /a:d /b
CD %ROOT_FOLDER%

FOR /F %%i IN (%FILE_LIST%) DO ROBOCOPY "%ROOT_FOLDER%\%%i" "%ROOT_FOLDER%\%%i\Documents" /MOVE /MIR /SEC /R:1 /W:1 /COPYALL
```

Unfortunately it doesn't work.
What it seems to be doing is :

- in each FolderX, a **Documents** subfolder is created : *good*
- the subfolders from folderX are moved into it : *good*
- but there is another **Documents** subfolder created in it too : *bad*
- the files under folderX are moved into this **Documents* subfolder : *bad*

Could you guys help me, please ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is ROBOCOPY is creating the `Documents` folder and begins copying, but the `/MOVE` parameters tells it move files and dirs so it creates the `Documents` folder again inside the first.

Try adding `/XD "Documents"` parameter to your ROBOCOPY.

Like this:

```
SET ROOT_FOLDER=C:\Folder\Root
SET WORK_FOLDER=C:\Temp
SET FILE_LIST=%WORK_FOLDER%\list.txt
DIR %ROOT_FOLDER% >%FILE_LIST% /a:d /b
CD %ROOT_FOLDER%

FOR /F %%i IN (%FILE_LIST%) DO ROBOCOPY "%ROOT_FOLDER%\%%i" "%ROOT_FOLDER%\%%i\Documents" /MOVE /MIR /SEC /R:1 /W:1 /COPYALL /XD "Documents"
```

Answer (score 1):

As I understand it, your problem is that *you don't know what Robocopy does in this case*. I suggest you to achieve the same process explicitly in a simple Batch file, so you always know what are you doing:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set "ROOT_FOLDER=C:\Folder\Root"

rem For each folder in root folder
cd "%ROOT_FOLDER%"
for /D %%a in (*) do (
   cd "%%a"

   rem Move all existent folders into "Documents" folder
   for /F "delims=" %%b in ('dir /B /A:D') do (
      md Documents 2> NUL
      move "%%b" "Documents\%%b"
   )

   rem Move all existent files into "Documents" folder
   md Documents 2> NUL
   move *.* Documents

   cd ..
)
```

Comment: Thank you, but I wanted to use ROBOCOPY in order to be able to move everything with the permissions and dates.